# Postgres generate_series excluding date ranges

Tags: postgresql, date, generate-series

I'm creating a subscription management system, and need to generate a list of upcoming billing date for the next 2 years.  I've been able to use generate_series to get the appropriate dates as such:

```
SELECT i::DATE
FROM generate_series('2015-08-01', '2017-08-01', '1 month'::INTERVAL) i
```

The last step I need to take is exclude specific date ranges from the calculation.  These excluded date ranges may be any range of time.  Additionally, they should not be factored into the time range for the generate_series.

For example, say we have a date range exclusion from '2015-08-27' to '2015-09-03'.  The resulting generate_series should exclude the date that week from the calculation, and basically **push all future month billing dates one week to the future**:

```
2015-08-01
2015-09-10
2015-10-10
2015-11-10
2015-12-10
```

Comment: Deleted answer, doesn't address the really hard part. Excluding the ranges is easy. The hard part is adjusting the pattern it recurs at, adding more time at the end to compensate for the skipped time ranges, and then adjusting the recurring dates. You're going to need a recursive CTE or a procedure to do this I think since the rows added by compensating for an exclusion at the end could themselves be excluded, so we have to then extend with more rows to test...

Comment: I also have the feeling your monthly billing combines poorly with allowing exclusions over ranges of days or weeks, because not every month is the same number of days long. You might want to think about billing every 30 days, rather than every month.

Comment: Your example appears to be wrong. The date advances by 9 days, but the interval is only 7 days long.

Comment: @CraigRinger Why do you assume that the 2 year range needs to be extended on the basis of excluded days? I do not read that in the question.

Comment: @Patrick From "push all future month billing dates one week to the future". Original poster should confirm that's the intent and provide *complete, correct expected results*. Please edit the question Eric.

Answer (score 4):

First you create a time series of dates over the next two years, `EXCEPT` your blackout dates:

```
SELECT dt
FROM generate_series('2015-08-01'::date, '2017-08-01'::date, interval '1 day') AS s(dt)
EXCEPT
SELECT dt
FROM generate_series('2015-08-27'::date, '2015-09-03'::date, interval '1 day') as ex1(dt)
```

Note that you can have as many `EXCEPT` clauses as you need. For individual blackout days (as opposed to ranges) you could use a `VALUES` clause instead of a `SELECT`.

Then you window over that time-series to generate row numbers of billable days:

```
SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY dt) AS rn, dt
FROM (<query above>) x
```

Then you select those days where you want to bill:

```
SELECT dt
FROM (<query above>) y
WHERE rn % 30 = 1; -- billing on the first day of the period
```

(This latter query following Craig's advice of billing by 30 days)

Yields:

```
SELECT dt
FROM (
  SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY dt) AS rn, dt
  FROM (
    SELECT dt
    FROM generate_series('2015-08-01'::date, '2017-08-01'::date, interval '1 day') AS s(dt)
    EXCEPT
    SELECT dt
    FROM generate_series('2015-08-27'::date, '2015-09-03'::date, interval '1 day') as ex1(dt)
  ) x
) y
WHERE rn % 30 = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to split the call to generate series for exclusions. Some thing like this:

- Union of 3 queries
- First query pulls dates from start to exclusion range from
- Second query pulls dates between exclusion range to and your end date
- Third query pulls dates when none of your series dates cross exclusion range

Note: You still need a way to loop through exclusion list (if you have one). Also this query may not be very efficient as such scenarios can be better handled through functions or procedural code.